# Material design solution for popovers

Tags: popup, material-design, microinteractions

Material design has no popovers, and I wonder what should be used as a replacement?

For example, how would you advise Product Hunt to replace their popover when they switch to material design?

[image: Product Hunt popover example]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Here's how...

See [this dropdown effect](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) for an example of how the Material Design physics can work for a popover.  A similar schematic is:

[image: popover]
The opacity fade, triangular callout indicator, and growth origin (top or center) are all valid options.

---

### Here's why

Material Design guidelines don't specify popovers, but the [specification of material properties](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/material-properties.html#) provide a clear set of properties that can be used to create popups.  The relevant material properties are:

- Material cannot occupy the same plane.  But material can be stacked.
- Material can be created in a plane. See [this video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQseERpUzUxRVRtMGs/whatismaterial-materialprop-movementmaterial-PaperPointExpand_xhdpi_005.webm).
- Material can change shape.  See [this video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQseERpUzUxRVRtMGs/whatismaterial-materialprop-movementmaterial-PaperPointExpand_xhdpi_005.webm).

So a popover sequence can be created with the following parameters:

1. Popover appears floating above the content.  Make sure shadows are compliant.  See [this](http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/environment.html#environment-light-shadow).
2. Popover is created in the plane over the content, as with [this video](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQseERpUzUxRVRtMGs/whatismaterial-materialprop-movementmaterial-PaperPointExpand_xhdpi_005.webm).

The dropdown demo at the top is mostly compliant with this set of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the Material Design spec has changed since this question was asked more than a year ago.

Under the current spec, Product Hunt would need to replace their popover with a dialog.  From the [spec](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html):

> Dialogs inform users about a specific task and may contain critical
>   information, require decisions, or involve multiple tasks.

[image]

Specifically the spec states that for list items (which is what Product Hunt would need to convert the content on this page to) you could use a simple dialog to provide details or actions about a list time from the spec:

> Simple menus display options for list items, whereas simple dialogs
>   can provide details or actions about a list item.

Here is an example similar to what Product Hunt would need:
[image]